# iOS app unable to be downloaded due to target

Tags: iphone, ios, submission

I submitted my first app last week (yay) and accidentally left the target as 4.3 which really limits who can download the app. I submitted an update that targeted 3.0, which was approved and is on the app store now. The binaries say 3.0, the requirements say 3.0, yet when I install it on a device without 4.3 it still says "This application requires iOS 4.3. You must update to iOS 4.3 in order to download and use this application."

Whats going on here? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Are you sure you set the target 3.0 and what was the current SDK for your binary?

Comment: I got it... see my below comment. Thanks everyone for the quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that you set the deployment target to 3.0 in your project and still have the 4.3 (or latest) setting in your target, which is more specific than the project's setting and overrides it.

Comment: Ok, well it finally just worked on my older device... I don't know why the new version would show up in the app store, yet the actual binary wasn't there yet, but I guess it just takes some time. So the answer is to just sit back and wait for apple to get everything updated on their servers.

Comment: You could have always checked in your app tunes account what was the current version rather than on app store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an app (4.2.1 compatible, previously only 4.3+) that hit the App Store last night and wouldn't install on a 4.2.1 device until this morning. Interestingly though, the new binary was most definitely on the store since it installed on an iOS 5 device and had new features bundled with the new build.

I assume there's some separate versioning server or something that isn't synchronized with the download servers, because it does seem to lag for several hours.